# What is this R structure and how do I get the indices?

Tags: r

I inherited someone's R code, and one of the key results of the code is a structure that R identifies only as "numeric" by class.  When I print it out as.matrix, here's what it looks like:

```
            [,1]
1   3.062500e-08
63  2.691366e-03
36  4.202501e-09
41  1.247481e-09
82  1.040101e-08
63  2.691366e-03
63  2.691366e-03
58  2.700624e-09
...
```

What I need to extract are those indices on the left - for example, for the first element the index is 1, for the second one it's 63, and so on.   I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I've tried to get it by using 'row' (does not work, always gives me 1), by turning this structure into a data frame and looking for colnames, but nothing works.  Could someone please help?

Comment: Try `dimnames(MyStructure)[[1]]`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `m` in the Note at the end has a class which is `matrix` and its mode is `numeric`.  It is a one column matrix with row names which seems to be what you have.

With that we can use `rownames` to get the row names.  The row names are always character so you might want to convert them to numeric as we show below.

```
as.numeric(rownames(m))
## [1]  1 63 36 41 82 63 63 58
```

### Note

We assume that the input is given as shown here:

```
m <- matrix(c(3.0625e-08, 0.002691366, 4.202501e-09, 1.247481e-09, 
  1.040101e-08, 0.002691366, 0.002691366, 2.700624e-09), 8, 
  dimnames = list(c("1", "63", "36", "41", "82", "63", "63", "58"), NULL))
```

giving:

```
> m
           [,1]
1  3.062500e-08
63 2.691366e-03
36 4.202501e-09
41 1.247481e-09
82 1.040101e-08
63 2.691366e-03
63 2.691366e-03
58 2.700624e-09

> class(m)
[1] "matrix"

> mode(m)
[1] "numeric"
```